# Вывод данных в DataGridView, Цикл

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, datagridview

Мне нужна помощь в одном вопросе.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Lagger's methode
    {
        if (int.TryParse(textBoxN.Text, out int n) && n >= 2)
        {
            double u = double.Parse(textBoxX3.Text); // шаг
            double j = double.Parse(textBoxX2.Text); // x2
            double x = double.Parse(textBoxX1.Text); // x1
            double l = 1, a = 1, b = 1 - x;
            for (double i = 1; i < n; i=i+u)
            {
                l = ((2 * i + 1 - x) * b - i * a) / (i + 1);
                a = b;
                b = l;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x, l);
            }
            textBoxRes.Text = l.ToString("F3");
        }
        else
            textBoxRes.Text = "Неверно указан N!";
    }
```

Это код, который находит ортогональный многочлен методом Лаггера. Мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь вводил диапазон решения X, после чего все решения с разными Х от х1 до х2 выводились в таблицу. Прилагаю вид приложения. Я совсем начинающий кодер и уверен, что вы найдете за что обругать, но прошу о помощи.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос? Что не работает то?

Comment: Забыл собственно задать вопрос. Не работает задумка. Результат выдает, но один,  а нужно, чтобы в таблицу попадали ответы всех решений со всеми целыми X от Х1 до Х2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (int.TryParse(textBoxN.Text, out int n) && n >= 2)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        double u = double.Parse(textBoxX3.Text); // шаг
        double x1 = double.Parse(textBoxX1.Text); // x1
        double x2 = double.Parse(textBoxX2.Text); // x2
        for (double x = x1; x <= x2; x += u);
        {
            double l = 1, a = 1, b = 1 - x;
            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            {
                l = ((2 * i + 1 - x) * b - i * a) / (i + 1);
                a = b;
                b = l;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(x, l);
        }
    }
    else
        textBoxRes.Text = "Неверно указан N!";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы очень сильно помогли! И кстати, к вопросу о том я ли задавал похожий вопрос. Нет, не я, это был мой товарищ по проекту, забавно, что мы не кооперировали действия, а вы и там и тут помогли. Хаха!